# chrome app how to triger chrome.printerProvider events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome app and it needs to communicate with printer very often so I will be sending data directly to the printer without a print dialog, for this chrome provides [`chrome.printerProvider`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider) api. But the api contains only events with callbacks I cant see a way to trigger this events. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to trigger those events outside of the print dialog.

`printerProvider` is an API to *provide* a new printer "driver", not to use an existing one.

Comment: what is the use case of such api

Comment: "Save to WhatsTheNextFormatAfterPDF", "Save to YourCloudDriveDuJour" for instance.

Comment: Or, a real driver together with `chrome.usb` or `chrome.bluetooth` or `chrome.sockets`.. Probably more targeted towards ChromeOS.